# Strange behaviour of h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using similar strategy for retrieving values in another page with other class, it is working fine there but in below case it is not showing values.

Any idea please?

Following is method for retrieving database values.

```
public List<ProductBean> getPc() {

int i = 0;

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
// if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse())
  List<ProductBean> pc= new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
 try {
    conn = getVConnection();
    String query = "select * from pictures";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    //pstmt.setInt(1,this.id);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
 pc.add(i,newProductBean(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
                    i++;
                }
          pstmt.close();
          rs.close();
          conn.close();


 }catch (Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Data : " + e.getMessage());
            }

 return pc;

 }
```

Following is  jsf page

```
<h:dataTable  styleClass="panelGridColums" value="#{tableBean.pc}" var="p" border="1" >
 <h:column>
<f:facet name="header">Product no</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{p.productNo}"/>
 </h:column>

 <h:column>
<f:facet name="header">Product name</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{p.p2name}"/>
 </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: it seems to be fine do you see anything in the console??

Comment: Nothing is displaying in console.

Comment: No values that i am trying to print are not displaying in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see any prints of the retrieved data or errors, then it simply means that the `pictures` table is empty. Or maybe you intend it to be the `products` table. Or maybe you're not running the code you think you're running.

Note that you've a compilation error in the posted code:

```
pc.add(i,newProductBean(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
```

But I'll assume it being a careless typo while composing the question.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, doing database interaction job in a getter method is a very bad idea. A getter can be called multiple times during bean's life. It should solely return the (prepopulated) property, not to do some expensive business job which ought to be done one-time. Move that piece of code to the bean constructor, preferably in flavor of a standalone class/method call.

```
public TableBean() throws SQLException {
    this.pc = productService.list();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

everything seems to be nice.
Maybe you can try one of the following points:

1. Mark your method with a breakpoint to see, if the method is really invoked
2. Try a System.out.println(rs.next()) to see, if it is true and the result set is filled.